# Tpump vs BTEQ import

Tags: sql, teradata

Hi I'm in beginner level in teradata.

I'm trying to understand which scenario is best suited for TPump and when bteq  import is best suited.

My case is requirement of small data files (around 1000records) 5-15 files is received every hour. Currently I'm using BTEQ import and running batch script every 30 mins to make it as near real-time.
I checked TPump docs, it says concatenate of files is not allowed, so what case TPump is best suited for

Answer (score 0):

Both BTEQ and TPump allow multiple sessions and packing data for multiple rows into one database message. TPump adds support for "serialization" to limit lock conflicts between sessions as well as the ability to log errors but continue loading.

For new applications, you should consider Teradata Parallel Transporter (TPT) instead. The `Stream` operator in TPT is quite similar to TPump while the `SQL Inserter` operator is similar to BTEQ import.